# How do you set a task to run as the current user at logon using vbs without admin rights?

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, scheduled-tasks

From the command line I can create a scheduled task that runs at logon without the need for admin privileges or the user entering a password to set the task. However I have to use an xml file to do this. here's an example xml, where the "Domain\User" part has to replaced at run time with the domain and name of the current user:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Author>Domain\User</Author>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <LogonTrigger>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <UserId>Domain\User</UserId>
    </LogonTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>Domain\User</UserId>
      <LogonType>InteractiveToken</LogonType>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>"C:\Windows\notepad.exe"</Command>
      <Arguments>/logon</Arguments>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

I can use the xml to create a task using the command:

```
schtasks /create /TN "Test Logon Task" /XML task.xml
```

This works fine but I'm trying to do the same thing in vbs without the need to write and then load an xml file for the user. I've been trying to adapt the [example from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381912%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but so far I've not been able to add the task without admin rights or prompting for the user's password.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably Schtasks.exe - From Microsoft documentation

> Permissions for *schtasks*
>
> - You must have permission to run the command. Any user can schedule a task on the local computer, and they can view and change the tasks that they scheduled. Members of the Administrators group can schedule, view, and change all tasks on the local computer.

And one of the parameters (`/sc onlogon`) allow to define a task that will run at logon.

Seems possible to be the answer, BUT i've not tried.

EDIT

Since schtasks proved not to be the answer, i've taken the original code from Microsoft and adapt to work (i hope, works for me)

```
'---------------------------------------------------------
' This sample schedules a task to start notepad.exe when a user logs on.
'---------------------------------------------------------

' A constant that specifies a logon trigger.
const TriggerTypeLogon = 9
' A constant that specifies an executable action.
const ActionTypeExecutable = 0   

const TASK_LOGON_INTERACTIVE_TOKEN = 3

'********************************************************
' Create the TaskService object.
Set service = CreateObject("Schedule.Service")
call service.Connect()

'********************************************************
' Get a folder to create a task definition in. 
Dim rootFolder
Set rootFolder = service.GetFolder("\")

' The taskDefinition variable is the TaskDefinition object.
Dim taskDefinition
' The flags parameter is 0 because it is not supported.
Set taskDefinition = service.NewTask(0) 

'********************************************************
' Define information about the task.

' Set the registration info for the task by 
' creating the RegistrationInfo object.
Dim regInfo
Set regInfo = taskDefinition.RegistrationInfo
regInfo.Description = "Task will execute Notepad when a " & _
    "specified user logs on."
regInfo.Author = "Author Name"

' Set the task setting info for the Task Scheduler by
' creating a TaskSettings object.
Dim settings
Set settings = taskDefinition.Settings
settings.StartWhenAvailable = True

'********************************************************
' Create a logon trigger.
Dim triggers
Set triggers = taskDefinition.Triggers

Dim trigger
Set trigger = triggers.Create(TriggerTypeLogon)

' Trigger variables that define when the trigger is active.
Dim startTime, endTime
startTime = "2013-10-22T10:49:02"
endTime = "2013-10-30T10:52:02"

WScript.Echo "startTime :" & startTime
WScript.Echo "endTime :" & endTime

trigger.StartBoundary = startTime
trigger.EndBoundary = endTime
trigger.ExecutionTimeLimit = "PT5M"    ' Five minutes
trigger.Id = "LogonTriggerId"
trigger.UserId = "MyDomainOrComputer\testUser"   ' Must be a valid user account   

'***********************************************************
' Create the action for the task to execute.

' Add an action to the task. The action executes notepad.
Dim Action
Set Action = taskDefinition.Actions.Create( ActionTypeExecutable )
Action.Path = "C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"

WScript.Echo "Task definition created. About to submit the task..."

'***********************************************************
' Deal with the password problems

taskDefinition.Principal.UserId = "MyDomainOrComputer\testUser"
taskDefinition.Principal.LogonType = TASK_LOGON_INTERACTIVE_TOKEN

'***********************************************************
' Register (create) the task.
const createOrUpdateTask = 6
call rootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition( _
    "Test Logon Trigger", taskDefinition, createOrUpdateTask, _
    Empty , Empty, TASK_LOGON_INTERACTIVE_TOKEN)

WScript.Echo "Task submitted."
```

Changed the RegisterTaskDefinition call to not pass credentials for the task, and configured del `Principal` object properties of the taskDefinition

Task registered with non admin user, without password prompt.

Comment: I've tried it, it doesn't work. You need to have the user's password. The only thing that I've got to work so far is importing an XML.

Comment: Maybe, you could create the task with the xml, use the Schedule.Service object and RegisteredTask property( [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382079%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446865%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to access task properties, and use GetSecurityDescriptor method to get the information you need to alimentate the SetSecurityDescriptor method when creating the task. Sorry, no time. Good luck.

Comment: That worked, thank you! It was the RegisterTaskDefinition call that turned out to the problem with my attempts.

Comment: How would you change the task conditions? I need my task to run regardless of whether it's on AC power or on battery.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai, I can not test it now, but `settings.DisallowStartIfOnBatteries = False` should do it