# Create a scheduled task using TASK_TRIGGER_LOGON in python

Tags: python, win32com, windows-task-scheduler

I’m trying to create a task that will run each time the current user logs in.

I’m having trouble finding any good examples or documentation.  The best example I’ve found is [this](https://dzone.com/articles/create-and-run-scheduled-task).

I tried swapping out `TASK_TRIGGER_DAILY = 2` for `TASK_TRIGGER_LOGON = 9`, removing `tigger.DaysInterval = 100` and using the associated objects like `trigger.Delay`, etc. found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/TaskSchd/logontrigger).

It always results in:

```
Pywintyps.com error: (-2147352567, ‘Exception occurred.’, (0, None, None, None, 0 -2147024809), None) on line 67: result = rootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(task_id, taskDef, TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE, "", "", RUNFLAGSENUM[run_flags] )
#username, password
```

Calling schtasks.exe works, but that requires a UAC elevation request which I’d like to avoid.

A working example or some relevant Python documentation would be great. I’m not well versed enough in C++ to translate it all over to Python.

Answer (score 6):

```
# Uses the COM Task Scheduler Interface to create a task
# scheduled to execute when the current user logs on.

import win32com.client
import os

computer_name = "" #leave all blank for current computer, current user
computer_username = ""
computer_userdomain = ""
computer_password = ""
action_id = "Test Task" #arbitrary action ID
action_path = r"c:\windows\system32\calc.exe" #executable path (could be python.exe)
action_arguments = r'' #arguments (could be something.py)
action_workdir = r"c:\windows\system32" #working directory for action executable
author = "Someone" #so that end users know who you are
description = "Run calc.exe when the current user logs on"
task_id = "Test Task"
task_hidden = False #set this to True to hide the task in the interface
username = ""
password = ""

#define constants
TASK_TRIGGER_LOGON = 9
TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE = 6
TASK_ACTION_EXEC = 0
TASK_LOGON_INTERACTIVE_TOKEN = 3

#connect to the scheduler (Vista/Server 2008 and above only)
scheduler = win32com.client.Dispatch("Schedule.Service")
scheduler.Connect(computer_name or None, computer_username or None, computer_userdomain or None, computer_password or None)
rootFolder = scheduler.GetFolder("\\")

#(re)define the task
taskDef = scheduler.NewTask(0)
colTriggers = taskDef.Triggers

trigger = colTriggers.Create(TASK_TRIGGER_LOGON)
trigger.Id = "LogonTriggerId"
trigger.UserId = os.environ.get('USERNAME') # current user account
#trigger.Enabled = False

colActions = taskDef.Actions
action = colActions.Create(TASK_ACTION_EXEC)
action.ID = action_id
action.Path = action_path
action.WorkingDirectory = action_workdir
action.Arguments = action_arguments

info = taskDef.RegistrationInfo
info.Author = author
info.Description = description

settings = taskDef.Settings
#settings.Enabled = False
settings.Hidden = task_hidden
#settings.StartWhenAvailable = True

#register the task (create or update, just keep the task name the same)
result = rootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(task_id, taskDef, TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE, "", "", TASK_LOGON_INTERACTIVE_TOKEN)

'''
# run the task once
task = rootFolder.GetTask(task_id)
task.Enabled = True
runningTask = task.Run("")
task.Enabled = False
'''
```

The hardest part was figuring out `TASK_LOGON_INTERACTIVE_TOKEN = 3` and not 4 as it's shown in the microsoft documentation [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/TaskSchd/logon-trigger-example--scripting-).  Found it in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522094/how-do-you-set-a-task-to-run-as-the-current-user-at-logon-using-vbs-without-admi).