# Python task scheduler via win32com on windows startup

Tags: python, windows, scheduled-tasks, boot, win32com

Hi everyone i am trying to set a new task in task scheduler on windows 10 via a python file , and i found here on stackoverflow and o dzone how to do it for a daily trigger or a log on trigger, but if i want to modify to a boot up trigger everything simply doesn't work i change the trigger number to 8 according to microsoft website [found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/starting-an-executable-on-system-boot) but it gives me and error

File "C:/Users/PTV4CLJ/Desktop/Python scripturi/test searcher/task.py", line 85, in 
    action.ID = action_id
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client__init__.py", line 481, in **setattr**
    raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (repr(self), attr))
AttributeError: '' object has no attribute 'ID'

Can someone help me?I want to set it also to run from two hours to two hours.

here is the code that i used

```
 import win32com.client

computer_name = "" #leave all blank for current computer, current user

computer_username = ""

computer_userdomain = ""

computer_password = ""

action_id = "Test Task" #arbitrary action ID

action_path = r"c:\windows\system32\calc.exe" #executable path (could be python.exe)

action_arguments = r'' #arguments (could be something.py)

action_workdir = r"c:\windows\system32" #working directory for action executable

author = "Someone" #so that end users know who you are

description = "testing task" #so that end users can identify the task

task_id = "Test Task"

task_hidden = False #set this to True to hide the task in the interface

username = ""

password = ""

run_flags = "TASK_RUN_NO_FLAGS" #see dict below, use in combo with username/password

#define constants

TASK_TRIGGER_STARTUP = 8

TASK_CREATE = 2

TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE = 6

TASK_ACTION_EXEC = 0

IID_ITask = "{148BD524-A2AB-11CE-B11F-00AA00530503}"

RUNFLAGSENUM = {

    "TASK_RUN_NO_FLAGS"              : 0,

    "TASK_RUN_AS_SELF"               : 1,

    "TASK_RUN_IGNORE_CONSTRAINTS"    : 2,

    "TASK_RUN_USE_SESSION_ID"        : 4,

    "TASK_RUN_USER_SID"              : 8

}

#connect to the scheduler (Vista/Server 2008 and above only)

scheduler = win32com.client.Dispatch("Schedule.Service")

scheduler.Connect(computer_name or None, computer_username or None, computer_userdomain or None, computer_password or None)

rootFolder = scheduler.GetFolder("\\")

#(re)define the task

taskDef = scheduler.NewTask(0)

colTriggers = taskDef.Triggers

trigger = colTriggers.Create(TASK_TRIGGER_STARTUP)


trigger.StartBoundary = "2019-09-19T08:00:00"#never start
trigger.EndBoundary="2019-09-20T08:00:00"

trigger.Enabled = False

colActions = taskDef.Actions

action = colActions.Create(TASK_ACTION_EXEC)

action.ID = action_id

action.Path = action_path

action.WorkingDirectory = action_workdir

action.Arguments = action_arguments

info = taskDef.RegistrationInfo

info.Author = author

info.Description = description

settings = taskDef.Settings

settings.Enabled = False

settings.Hidden = task_hidden

#register the task (create or update, just keep the task name the same)

result = rootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(task_id, taskDef, TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE, "", "", RUNFLAGSENUM[run_flags] ) #username, password

#run the task once

task = rootFolder.GetTask(task_id)

task.Enabled = True

runningTask = task.Run("")

task.Enabled = False
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a wild guess and say that it should look like this:

```
action.Id = action_id
```

Note that all other fields are camel case.

It looks like [`IAction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/taskschd/nn-taskschd-iaction) has a [`put_Id`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/taskschd/nf-taskschd-iaction-put_id) method, and I assume the Python wrapper preserves the case of the fields it exposes as attributes.

Comment: Hi yes you fixed one error but the problem is still around there now i am getting                File "C:/Users/PTV4CLJ/Desktop/Python scripturi/test searcher/task.py", line 87, in <module>
    action.Path = action_path

Comment: [`IExecAction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/taskschd/nn-taskschd-iexecaction) has a `put_Path` so I'm not sure what the problem is there.

Comment: So as i searched for a way to start an exe on boot, i found two codes that look like what i needed on is here <  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51172706/create-a-scheduled-task-using-task-trigger-logon-in-python> and one here <  https://dzone.com/articles/create-and-run-scheduled-task   > as i tested both of them they were working fine but when i changed them to start at boot i keep getting those kind of errors as seen above